# m2e Does Not Detect Any Jars in Local Repository

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, m2e

In my Java project, which has a maven 'nature', m2e version 1.0.10020110804 does NOT detect any jars located in my local repo. I can successfully compile/install using maven from the command line, but when I open the project in Eclipse I'm notified of 100+ (cannot be resolved to a type) errors. Does anyone know how to resolve this problem? I've tried updating dependencies and cleaning my project, but neither works. My local repo is set in m2e under 'User Settings'.

Comment: If you're 100% percent sure that you're local repository path is correct, then one problem could be that either your `settings.xml` or your project's `pom.xml` is malformed. If your `pom.xml` has an un-closed XML tag for example, then m2e won't able to resolve your dependencies and will shove error messages into your face.

Comment: Maven still shows "BUILD SUCCESS" when importing a jar and referencing an incorrect path to a jar.  Its easy to overlook a failed import.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recently faced the same problem. The root cause was that I imported my project as a generic project and later added maven and java natures to it. I resolved the issue by closing and removing the project from my workspace and re-importing as a maven project and then syncing it with my local repo. HTH.

Answer (score 4):

**M2e needs to be configured to use your local , home repository .  In general, one would expect it to do so automatically... But in your case, its using a different home repository.**

I feel your pain here - I have seen it use a default repo inside of eclipse in some cases, which can cause problems if you have / need your own local .m2 directory.

I believe that when I first got this problem, I was installing the m2e plugin without having installed first setting maven up as a standalone application.  In this case, it might be that the m2e plugin uses a local maven copy/repo  .

**So the moral of the story is : You need to configure the plugin to "see" and "use" your M2_HOME correctly.**

There are some good tips on getting the settings right here : [Eclipse m2eclipse getting dependancies from local repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2814555/eclipse-m2eclipse-getting-dependancies-from-local-repository)

By editing the m2e plugin settings through the Preferences window, you can ensure that m2e is accessing the right Maven HOME directory, and that will solve this problem.

Comment: The local repo is correctly set under: `Window > Preferences > Maven > User Settings` to `/home/ari/.m2/repository` but I'm still facing the problem.

Comment: @Ari Can you try to go to Preferences->Maven->Installations and select a different maven installation (i.e. the one on your machine, rather than the embedded one) ?  ALSO under "User Settings", try clicking "reindex" - m2eclipse ultimately will read repos from the maven index.

Answer (score 0):

did you try refreshing the workspace?

I am having a similar experience, and I've tried all those thing because it wasn't recognizing the Rhino jar in my unit tests.  A lot less errors, but still a couple.  Had to close the project, close eclipse, run mvn clean compile, open eclipse, open the project.

Comment: I just tried your suggestion, but unfortunately, it did not work for me.